# Converting atom theme to visual studio code

Tags: colors, themes, atom-editor, visual-studio-code

I put really much effort in developing my own color scheme for atom (and webstorm), where every color means the same thing to me.

I tried using `base16` but could not fit it into it.

Recently I switched from Atom to Visual Studio Code and really want to use my own color scheme. Does anybody know how to convert it from atom style (I think it's scss) to vscode style (tmTheme).

Here are the themes:
https://atom.io/themes/bluloco-dark-syntax
https://github.com/uloco/webstorm-bluloco-scheme